# How to get the current temporary "anonymous" active user key?

Tags: google-apps-script

The Reference guide for [Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#gettemporaryactiveuserkey) says the method returns "a temporary key that is unique to the active user" and that this key "rotates every 30 days and is unique to the script".
Actually the method returns a temporary key also for "anonymous" sessions, indicating that no user is currently logged in.
Is this temporary "anonymous user" key stored somewhere? Since it changes every 30 days, is there any method to get the current "anonymous key" to compare it against the one returned by the getTemporaryActiveUserKey() method?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've recently built something using this very param so I think I just might know what you need.

To your question though -

> Is this temporary "anonymous user" key stored somewhere?

The answer is **No**. The `Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey()` is not automatically stored somewhere.

You can however, store it using [`PropertiesService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) (or practically any other place that you're comfortable accessing like Sheets, Notes etc.) and one of the implementations of this can be found [here](https://github.com/schoraria911/google-apps-script/blob/master/Twilio/Authy/Code.gs#L3).

Hope this helps.